# split string by multple white-space and characters

Tags: java

I have this string.

> File Name : foto1.jpg

I want to put the elements in a string of 2 fields like 
`{"File Name", "foto1.jpg"}`. How can I do this in java?

I'm trying...

```
split("\\s{2,}:\\s")
```

...but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

`\\s+:\\s+` should work for you :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String s = "File Name : foto1.jpg";
    String[] arr = s.split("\\s+:\\s+"); // + means one or more
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));

}
```

O/P :

```
[File Name, foto1.jpg]
```

Comment: its reasonable but in `REGEX` we work on every detail `text` or in this case `String` represent this work but if instad of `foto1.jpg` we have `foto1` compiler dont throw anyThig and everyThing its look good but its not and more details we have here we dont mentioned

Comment: @Hosseini - The output would still be the same even if you had `foto1` instead of `foto1.jpg`

Comment: its not we dont reconize image if image have name like `foto1.jpg` and we have `foto1` in my code we not mention image extension and if instead of `foto1.jpg` we add wrong extension like `foto1.jgp`

Comment: thank but it don't work neither, there are multiple white-space between file name and : no a single white space

Comment: File Name 'multiple white-space': 'single white-space' foto1.jpg

Comment: @thieba - It still works. I tried your input and got `[File Name, foto1.jpg]` as output

Answer (score 1):

You can just spilt it based on regx as : in your case. Below is the example to get it.

```
public class StringSplit {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a = "File Name : foto1.jpg";
        String[] values = a.split(":", 2);
        System.out.println(values[0].trim());
        System.out.println(values[1].trim());
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm glad this helped you @thieba